# copy a file only when the apt task installed the package the first time

Tags: ansible

I'm wondering how best to achieve this (hopefully) simple task in Ansible:

In the playbook, when the dnsmasq apt package gets installed the first time round, backup /etc/dnsmasq.conf to /etc/dnsmasq.conf.orig before proceeding with any other tasks.

Something like the code below?

```
- name: 'Ensure dnsmasq package is installed'
  apt:
    name: dnsmasq
    state: present
  notify: Backup original /etc/dnsmasq.conf file

- name: Backup original /etc/dnsmasq.conf file
  copy:
    remote_src: yes
    src: /etc/dnsmasq.conf
    dest: /etc/dnsmasq.conf.orig
  when: ONLY IF WE JUST INSTALLED THE PACKAGE ABOVE
```

Comment: `force: no` option in `copy` module will copy the file only if it does not exists (i.e. you never installed and copied the original file).

Comment: Thank you @Zeitounator that did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

> `force: no` option in copy module will copy the file only if it does not exists (i.e. you never installed and copied the original file). – Zeitounator yesterday

Using 'force' did the trick and is the simplest method, thanks guys!

(creating this as an answer as I can't mark a comment as an answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use `dpkg-divert` for that. It allows you to redirect the distribution's configuration file into different place (f.e. `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` into `/etc/dnsmasq.conf.dist`), so your configuration file will never be overwritten by the distribution version, and distribution file (copy) will be saved into separate file (and will be updated together with package). See `man dpkg-dist` for available options.